# Microsoft CRM Web service - LookupAttribute Metadata (One-to-many, or one-to-one)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, generic-programming

I need to make a generic exporter/importer from a Microsoft CRM 2011 system and I cant find out if a LookupAttribute is a one-to-one- or one-to-many-relation.

E.x. 
I have an Entity called an "E-mail".

And e-mail can have one "From" (which is a lookup attribute that does its lookup into multiple other Entity-lists)

It can then have multiple "To" (also referencing out into multiple entity-lists as a lookup attribute).

The conclusions I just made are stuff that i figured out by using the web portal for MS CRM. I just cant find any way to see in the metadata of these Entities or Attributes if its a one-to-one- or a on-to-many-relation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509035.aspx#BKMK_CreateLookupAttribute

I've looked at this example on how to create these kinds of relations, but it hasnt gotten me any futher.

Does anyone have any experience with generic export/import with MS CRM 2011 that can help me?

Comment: What are you trying to export/import? Are you trying to transfer a solution or just some customization's?

From and To are not Lookup fields, they are special CRM fields called Party List fields which you cannot manually create. Basically they are 1:N to Activity Party, where activity party can be a reference to any of the defined system entities for that party list field, or it can be a simple string with an email.

CRM doesn't support one-to-one relationships.

Your question is too general. Please make it clear what you need help or direction with.

Answer (score 3):

CRM has a two types of relationships:

- One to many: a lookup on one entity, a grid on the other.
- Many to many: a grid on both entities.

There is no such thing as a one to one relationship. You are looking at a lookup. 90% of the lookups you see are simple, you can select one record of one entity type.

However, there are special system field lookups, named activity party. These muddy the waters a little. Some activity party lookups allow multiple record selections, some link to entities of multiple types. Which means you can have an activity party lookup with multiple records of multiple entity types. I suppose you could call this a "one to many (records) of many (entities)".

For example on an email; the `To` field can be populated with multiple account and contact records. Whilst the `From` field can only have one record, but that can be a system user or queue. The `To` and `From` are both examples of activity party lookups.

So in terms of what you are trying to do, you need to examine:
`AttributeMetadata.AttributeType` to see if its a party list.
`LookupAttributeMetadata.Targets` to see what record types are allowed in the lookup.

The following code shows how to do this for a couple of different fields.

```
RetrieveAttributeRequest attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
{
    EntityLogicalName = "email",
    LogicalName = "to",
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

RetrieveAttributeResponse result = Service.Execute(attributeRequest) as RetrieveAttributeResponse;

Trace.WriteLine("Email - To");
Trace.WriteLine("AttributeMetadata.AttributeType: " + result.AttributeMetadata.AttributeType);
Trace.WriteLine("LookupAttributeMetadata.Targets: " + ((LookupAttributeMetadata)result.AttributeMetadata).Targets.CollectionToString(", "));

attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
{
    EntityLogicalName = "email",
    LogicalName = "from",
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

result = Service.Execute(attributeRequest) as RetrieveAttributeResponse;

Trace.WriteLine("Email - From");
Trace.WriteLine("AttributeMetadata.AttributeType: " + result.AttributeMetadata.AttributeType);
Trace.WriteLine("LookupAttributeMetadata.Targets: " + ((LookupAttributeMetadata)result.AttributeMetadata).Targets.CollectionToString(", "));

attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
{
    EntityLogicalName = "account",
    LogicalName = "parentaccountid",
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

result = Service.Execute(attributeRequest) as RetrieveAttributeResponse;

Trace.WriteLine("Account - Parent Account Id");
Trace.WriteLine("AttributeMetadata.AttributeType: " + result.AttributeMetadata.AttributeType);
Trace.WriteLine("LookupAttributeMetadata.Targets: " + ((LookupAttributeMetadata)result.AttributeMetadata).Targets.CollectionToString(", "));
```

And the output:

```
Email - To
AttributeMetadata.AttributeType: PartyList
LookupAttributeMetadata.Targets: account, contact, lead, queue, systemuser

Email - From
AttributeMetadata.AttributeType: PartyList
LookupAttributeMetadata.Targets: queue, systemuser

Account - Parent Account Id
AttributeMetadata.AttributeType: Lookup
LookupAttributeMetadata.Targets: account
```

Comment: great answer James, yesterday I checked the `AttributeType`property but didn't find the `Targets` one

Comment: If you look at your output (its the same i got) - How can you tell from that output that "To" is a "one-to-many-of-many" and "From" is a "one-to-one-of-many" ?

Comment: @CoBolt I did look into that, but at the moment I'm not sure how to determine it in the code above. You might be able to find the answer to that in a `RetrieveRelationshipRequest` (or otherwise interrogating the relationships). As a fall back position; as we mere mortals (e.g. not Microsoft) cant customise the system to add `PartyList` then the number of `PartyList` fields is pretty much static within a major version of CRM. So you could map these details manually - not as nice but might be the quickest way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I have looked into the relationships of the E-mail-Entity. But I havent found any that are linked to either the "from"- or "to"-attribute. Like you say the fall back we could make a special case out of activities, but I would really like to avoid this